# One of my control is not showing in intellisense

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, splitcontainer

I have two split containerss in my VB.NET WinForm `SplitContainer1` and `SplitContainer2`, however i renamed my `Splitcontainer1` to `SC1` and now its not showing in intellisense while coding, also when i type in manually it gives me error.

So i finally, rolled back to the previous name i.e. from `SC1` to again `SplitContainer1` and still it is not showing up. What would be the possible reason and how can i fix it. As my `SplitContainer2` is working fine and it is accessible through code window.

One more thing my `SplitContainer1` is also assailable through design mode.

**EDIT:**

When i use `SplitContainer1` in code window it says `Error 1 'SplitContainer1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

I don't know whats happening as when i try to add another SplitContainer to the form with the name `SplitContainer1` it says that it is already used in form.

Comment: Have you rebuilt the solution?

Comment: @Robert I have done some changes in my question, please reconsider

Comment: have you tried to restart VisualStudio? sometimes it helps..

Comment: @trippino Yes i did, but its still the same

Comment: I think some designer code may help here..

Comment: You'll need to give us more details.  Are you trying to use `SplitContainer1` from within the form's code, or in another class?  Can you access all the other controls from that same line in the code?  If so, then you'll need to look at the code generated by the designer to see where it is declared, what it's actually called, and how it's different from the other controls.